# Gmail API - sending email with oAuth2.0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to create a [web page](http://hiro.collegewebserver.com/COSW200/hw13/gmailtest.html) that sends an email only using javascript and Gmail API. I have set up my developer's console to use the API and also created an API key and a credential.

I have adapted this [example code](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#HowitlooksinJavaScript), and so far I think I got to the point of loading the GMail API. (or.. 400 means something is wrong?) The console log shows:

```
POST https://content.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json 400 (OK)

zu @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:85
n @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:85
Cu @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:85
(anonymous function) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:86
g @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:55
c @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:46
```

And when I try authenticating with oAuth2.0 through a url:

```
var code;

$.get("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email&
  redirect_uri=http://hiro.collegewebserver.com/COSW200/hw13/gmailtest.html&
  response_type=token&client_id=386373199858-o1rt7qj3gt99gbfg6pqpr0g6i92urq9t.apps.googleusercontent.com&
  approval_prompt=force",

  function (returnedValue) { code = returnedValue; });
```

I get this message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email&
redirect_uri=http://h…3gt99gbfg6pqpr0g6i92urq9t.apps.googleusercontent.com&
approval_prompt=force.

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://hiro.collegewebserver.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've read other posts that say this may be due to cross origin requests being blocked? Someone wrote that there are ways to work around this like using JSONP?

If someone can enlighten me as to what I'm missing here, I would really appreciate! :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make an ajax call to Google to get your access code. The idea of OAuth2 is that you first redirect the user to accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/your_settings. In your case:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email&redirect_uri=http://hiro.collegewebserver.com/COSW200/hw13/gmailtest.html&response_type=token&client_id=386373199858-o1rt7qj3gt99gbfg6pqpr0g6i92urq9t.apps.googleusercontent.com&approval_prompt=force
```

In this Google environment the user can login with his/her account. One of the settings you provide is the redirect_uri.

Since you whitelisted http://hiro.collegewebserver.com/COSW200/hw13/ as one of the Authorized redirect URIs in your Google Developers Console and this url is related to your client_id, no other application than your website can use your client_id to receive an authorization code.

After login the user will be redirected to this redirect_uri, with the code as one of the parameters.

This will look something like this:

```
http://hiro.collegewebserver.com/COSW200/hw13/#access_token=yb27…jK0AVtilhnrJDcuTISgIB5LiNtKLMut1kVvPW69w&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

After that you would have to extract the access token from the url. With this access token you can authorise the user and make use of the scopes you entered. This can be done with an ajax call.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages?access_token=' + access_token
}).then(function(response){
//your code
})
```

You could also put the access_token in the header of the call:

```
Authorization: Bearer access_token
```

Another option is to use the API Client Library for JavaScript (Beta): https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript

Although it is in Beta and the basic workflow is the same, it might give you clearer examples.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer! I now understand that you actually have to first move to the Google's OAuth url and then get redirected back to your original page. Actually someone has written a tutorial showing how to do this using a pop-up window, so I'm following that now. Anyway, thank you for your gracious help! :)

Comment: You're welcome, good to hear this @morezoom. I hope everything works out.